# Convert hyphen to underscore in permalinks

Tags: functions, permalinks, filters, actions, pluggable

I would like to use underscore in my permalinks instead of hyphen.

Current permalink:

```
www.example.com/2013/01/hello-this-is-a-test-post/
```

Desired permalink

```
www.example.com/2013/01/hello_this_is_a_test_post/
```

I have tried [some solutions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/17460/5074) mentioned here in stacexchange. But they were not working.

Comment: what about writing a script to change the slug of every post?

Comment: Dashes seem to be the more reliable word separator from what I can tell. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Which _some solutions_? And note Google treats `-` as word separator, but not `_`. You will hurt yourself. :)

Comment: @toscho I've tried [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/17460/5074). If google doesn't treat underscore as word separator, why does some popular sites use it?. Example [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages). Example wordpress [codex link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

Comment: @s_ha_dum underscore looks more pretty than hyphen. Example [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages)

Comment: Limitations in MediaWiki. Do not take this as a positive example.

Comment: @toscho Thanks for your advise. I dropped the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho) advised me like this.

> Google treats - as word separator, but not _. You will hurt yourself.
>   :)

He was 100% true. Here is [an article](http://www.ecreativeim.com/blog/2011/03/seo-basics-hyphen-or-underscore-for-seo-urls/) that explains it. So I dropped the idea.

But if you still looking for a solution here is the answer.

Answered by [this stackoverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random)

> Hunt down the following file: `wp-includes/formatting.php`
>
> Jump down to the `sanitize_title_with_dashes` function. You'll find
>   this section of code inside:
>
> ```
> $title = strtolower($title);
> $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
> $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
> $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
> $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
> $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
> $title = trim($title, '-');
> ```
>
> Swap out all of the dashes/hyphens (`-`) for underscores (`_`) like
>   so:
>
> ```
> $title = strtolower($title);
> $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
> $title = str_replace('.', '_', $title);
> $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
> $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $title);
> $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '_', $title);
> $title = trim($title, '_');
> ```
>
> Note that any posts you've created before this change, and rely on the
>   `%postname%` permalink structure tag, will be broken.
>
> In that case you'll need to go back and republish those post so the
>   dashes are swapped out for the underscores. Or just write yourself a
>   little SQL to replace them.

Comment: I don't get it, then why would wikipedia use underscores?? and I'm using farsi letter in my url, comapre `یک-پست` with `یک_پست`! I definitely like underscore here. but I need to confirm underscores are bad for seo

Comment: I got this finally, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/445

Answer (score 1):

it can be done easily without any codes or plugin just go to pages dashboard, click Quick Edit" which url you want to change. Now add underscore. Update and done

Answer (score 0):

I initially did this but with every update to Wordpress I'd have to make the manual change again, so I made this plugin in case it helps anyone: http://wordpress.org/plugins/underscores-in-permalinks/